# How to verify the response from api while writing test with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am working on a `Rails` project where I have to test the API with Cucumber. I have to test a POST type API and I need to verify its response. I have tried something like:

```
When(/^I make abc API call$/) do
  @url = 'http://example.com/api/abc'
  @params = '{
                data: {
                  type: "abc",
                  attributes: {
                    title: "example",
                    all_day: "0",
                    start_date: "1409175049",
                    end_date: "1409175049"
                  }
                }
              }'
  @login_token = 'pHufpGplLTYJnmWh5cqKoA'
end

Then(/^It should return success for abc$/) do
  post 'http://example.com/api/abc', body: @params,
                                 headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json',
                                            'login_token' => @login_token,
                                            'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
end
```

But I am not sure how to verify the status code from the response and any attributes from the response. Something like:

```
Then(/^It should return success for abc$/) do
  post 'http://example.com/api/abc', body: @params,
                                 headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json',
                                            'login_token' => @login_token,
                                            'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  .to_return(status: 200, body: '{ title: "abc" }')
end
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Capybara` this should work for you:

```
Then /^I should get a response with status (\d+)$/ do |status|
  response = post 'http://example.com/api/abc', body: @params,
                                                headers: { 'Accept' => 'application/json',
                                                           'login_token' => @login_token,
                                                           'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  response.status_code.should include(status.to_i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks i also tried the same its worked now i am facing two issues one is it does not set the headers it send this headers part in the body any idea? and another issue is i have pass the url to test the api but still it doesnot call that url but checks in the application

Comment: Normally, you would use something like `page.driver.header 'Accept', 'application/json'`. But Capybara is used to test user behaviour not APIs. I'd use MiniTest, Rspec or other test suite to do API testing. I think your tool of choice here will cause you troubles every now and then. If my answer was helpful and fixed the initial question remember to mark it as a correct answer.